# match row names of two data frames and subset only matching rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would  like to subset "z" data frame based on rows from "b" data frame

```
>z
    Fox Prox Sox
ABC 1   2    3
DEF 1   1    0
GHI 1   0    2
ABD 1   3    0
AAB 2   3    2

>b
ABC 1
DEF 7
ABD 1

>output
   Fox Prox Sox
ABC 1   2    3
DEF 1   1    0
AAD 2   3    2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use the `rownames` from `b` to subset `z`.

```
z[rownames(b),] 
#    Fox Prox Sox
#ABC   1    2   3
#DEF   1    1   0
#ABD   1    3   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the merge function is what you need:

```
newdf <- merge(z, b, by =letters)
```

or else I think you can do this dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

z <- z %>%
  filter(letters %in% b$letters)
```

I put "letters" as the name of the first column. Because I didn't see a column name. You might first have to do this:

```
colnames(z) <- c("letters", "Fox", "Prox", "Sox")
```